# If the input was no number php

Tags: php, forms, validation

I made a form where someone could order a product, (they have to order at least 1 product in order to continue) when they click submit they will be taken to a confirmation page with the order and their personal details where they can print or change their order.

But if someone wants to they can change the script within the source code and enter text, images or - numbers using html code or just -10. So they can order -10 of a product.

Now i wanted to make some kind of protection on the confirmation page that if $number is no number or if $number contains something else then numbers it will go echo ""; so it won't show up.

i'm running this array which will place the order in the confirmation page table:

```
    $total_price = 0;       
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($products as $key => $product){
      $number = isset($_POST[$key])?$_POST[$key]:'';
            if (!$number){
            $count++;
            echo "";
            } else {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $product;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo htmlspecialchars($number);                 
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                $price = $prices[$count]* $number;
                echo "&#8364 ", number_format($price, 2);
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $total_price += $price;
        $count++;
        }
    }
```

So whenever !$number (the field is empty) it will skip the product. So only products that have something put in the input field it will show on my order. But as i told you before you can enter letters negative numbers whatever you want. Caus it only checks if the field is empty or not.

Any help is greatly appreciated, maybe someone knows a better way of protection, using preferably PHP since it can't be found in the source code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect if a string contains a numeric string use [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php):

```
if(is_numeric($input)) {
    echo 'Input is a number';
}
```

Comment: Works exactly as i want to. Thanks. Added if (is_numeric($number) && $number > 0) so it wont show negative numbers either.

Comment: Ok, you can use this ten minutes to read [this](http://php.net/manual/de/filter.filters.validate.php). You can learn some more elaborated validation concepts of PHP. (if you are interested)

Comment: @AshrafSamhouri I don't know, whenever i try to accept his answer it says that i can accept an asnwer in ** minutes. Starting from 10.

Comment: Aaaah okay. You seem to have talked about it in your comments :P ? I'm sorry for being a pain in the a** :)

Answer (score 0):

You could start with [is_numeric](https://www.php.net/is_numeric) , then when you're sure it's a number, test if it's over 0 ...